# In-App-Purchase: A/B-testing possible/allowed?

Tags: in-app-purchase, ab-testing

Is it possible and allowed to have A/B-testing for in-app-purchase for iOS and Android? I heard it's not allowed for iOS but didn't find an official document.

What about Android?

Answer (score 3):

For iOS you can only test in app purchase in sandbox mode.

Now with the latest updates, iOS has launched percentage rollout feature so you can release your feature to partial users and see how your new feature is doing and then rollout to complete set.

And as for android- try going through below link and see if it helps:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/in-app-a-b-testing.html

Comment: This link not working. Can you show equivalent? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to do A/B testing with in-app purchases but you will need to implement some custom code and either roll your own analytics platform or integrate with a third party.

If you are simply testing only the descriptions and or images that are displayed with your in-app purchase you can hard code the different variants on your client or fetch them from your own server instead of using the descriptions stored in iTunes Connect.

If you are experimenting with pricing you will have to create different versions of your in-app purchase in iTunes connect or Google Play and then your client or server can decide which price(s) to display and only show that subset of IAPs.

There are several third party analytics tools that work with iOS and Android that can help you track the performance of the different variants.

Comment: There is no need to implement everything on your own any more. There is a service and an open-source SDK for that called Mage (iOS, Android, React-Native). Mage offers automatic in-app purchase price testing and optimization. Website: https://www.getmage.io/, Github Repos: https://github.com/getmageio . Full discloser, I am the Co-Founder of Mage. We had the same problem for years now and decided to build a tool to solve that problem. Mage has a free plan for small apps!

Comment: @mklb should I create multiple SKUs if I decided to use Mag for iOS?